# Is there a metric measuring independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence

Let $a,b,c,d$ be random variables.

Is there a metric $d$ which has a property that (1) if d(a,b)=0, then $a$ & $b$ are almost independent and (2) if $d(a,b)<d(c,d)$, then the pair $(a,b)$ are more independent than the pair $(c,d)$?

For example, consider the total correlation (TC) metric. (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_correlation)

If $TC(a)=0$, we can say that marginals of $a$ are independent, so we can consider this metric as measuring the independence of marginals. However, I am not sure whether we can say that the marginals of $a$ are more mutually independent than $b$ if $TC(a)<TC(b)$. I think this is problematic since we cannot say that the pair $(a,b)$ are closer than $(c,d)$ when $KL(a|b)<KL(c|d)$..